# Why do I get garbage output when printing an int[]?

Tags: java, printing, for-loop, character

My program is suppose to count the occurrence of each character in a file ignoring upper and lower case. The method I wrote is:

```
public int[] getCharTimes(File textFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(textFile);

  int[] lower = new int[26];
  char current;
  int other = 0;

  while(inFile.hasNext()){
     String line = inFile.nextLine();
     String line2 = line.toLowerCase();
     for (int ch = 0; ch < line2.length(); ch++) {
        current = line2.charAt(ch);
        if(current >= 'a' && current <= 'z')
           lower[current-'a']++;
        else
           other++;
     }
  }

  return lower;
 }
```

And is printed out using:

```
for(int letter = 0; letter < 26; letter++) {
             System.out.print((char) (letter + 'a'));
       System.out.println(": " + ts.getCharTimes(file));
            }
```

Where ts is a `TextStatistic` object created earlier in my main method. However when I run my program, instead of printing out the number of how often the character occurs it prints:

```
a: [I@f84386 
b: [I@1194a4e 
c: [I@15d56d5 
d: [I@efd552 
e: [I@19dfbff 
f: [I@10b4b2f
```

And I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ts.getCharTimes(file) returns int array.

print ts.getCharTimes(file)[letter]

Answer (score 9):

Check out the signature of your method; it is returning an array of ints.

ts.getCharTimes(file) returns int array. So to print use:

```
ts.getCharTimes(file)[letter]
```

**You are also running the method 26 times, which is likely to be wrong.** Since the call context (parameters and such) is not affected by the iterations of the loop consider changing the code to:

```
int[] letterCount = ts.getCharTimes(file);
for(int letter = 0; letter < 26; letter++) {
  System.out.print((char) (letter + 'a'));
  System.out.println(": " + letterCount[letter]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not garbage; it's a feature!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args);
    System.out.println("long:    " + new long[0]);
    System.out.println("int:     " + new int[0]);
    System.out.println("short:   " + new short[0]);
    System.out.println("byte:    " + new byte[0]);
    System.out.println("float:   " + new float[0]);
    System.out.println("double:  " + new double[0]);
    System.out.println("boolean: " + new boolean[0]);
    System.out.println("char:    " + new char[0]);
}
```

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@70922804
long:    [J@b815859
int:     [I@58cf40f5
short:   [S@eb1c260
byte:    [B@38503429
float:   [F@19908ca1
double:  [D@6100ab23
boolean: [Z@72e3b895
char:    [C@446b7920
```

"The classes for arrays have strange names that are not valid identifiers;"—[*The Java Virtual Machine Specification*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#23409).

Addendum: See also [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).