# how to Update jtable with AES_DECRYPT

Tags: java, swing, jtable, aes, defaulttablemodel

I would like to update the `JTable` without `AES_ENCRYPT` the data is can be updated and viewed, but since the data is encrypted each time i try to call this method the data is still encrypted. how can I use  solve this issue ?

```
private void Update_Table(){



     try{
         String sql  = "SELECT ID, AES_DECRYPT(FirstName,  'uk112') "
           + "AS FirstName, AES_DECRYPT( MiddleName,  'uk112') "
           + "AS MiddleName, AES_DECRYPT(LastName,  'uk112') "
           + "AS LastName, DOB, AES_DECRYPT(Gander,  'uk112')"
           + "AS Gander, AES_DECRYPT(Address,  'uk112')"
           + "AS Address, AES_DECRYPT(City,  'uk112' ) "
           + "AS City, AES_DECRYPT(PostCode,  'uk112')"
           + "AS PostCode FROM Customer";
   pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs =pst.executeQuery(sql);
   CTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
   pst.close();
   rs.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }   
  }
```

whenever i try call the Update_Table method  in order to update The `JTable` this happens

[image]

Comment: have you tried geting data from `rs` like `rs.getString("FirstName")` ? does it give `encryped` data or `decrypted`? 
if it gives `encypted` data, is it possible that you encypted data twice while inseing to DB?
if it gives `decrypted` data can you show us code of `DbUtils`?
If it gives

Comment: I have only encrypted the data once, but how would  use 'rs.getString("FirstName")'

Comment: after `  pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs =pst.executeQuery(sql);` use `while(rs.next()){String name=rs.getString("FirstName");
System.out.println(name);}` and check console

Comment: It decrypts it .... by the way thanks for your effort

Comment: Then may be you are encoding it inside DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel somehow. if you can show code snippet of that we wil be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably *not* still encrypted. That's the expected output of the [default renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2558031/230513), the result is produced by `toString()` invoked with a `byte` array. In your [custom renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer), you can convert the array to a `String` using a suitable constructor, but you'll need to specify the same encoding used by the database.

Comment: I have decrypted twice, is it not possible to decrypt the data for more than once ?

Comment: I don't know. Try `Arrays.toString()` to see what's in each `byte []`.